# No output with cURL and Google Maps API

Tags: api, curl

there is no output with address..what's wrong with this PHP code? Is there any solution?

Thx

```
 <?php
            $str = "Street 1 ZIP City";
            $adr = $str;
            $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?adress=$adr&sensor=false";

            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
            $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);




            $address = json_decode($curlData);
            print_r($address);
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your request string: `adress` instead of `address`. The correct request string is:

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$adr&sensor=false";
```

And also you should better use PHP's `urlencode()` function for `$adr` parameter before pasting it into the request string.

I've copy&paste your code with changes listed before,i.e. I have:

```
            $str = "Street 1 ZIP City";
            $adr = urlencode($str);
            $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$adr&sensor=false";

            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
            $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);




            $address = json_decode($curlData);
            print_r($address);
```

Output in my browser for this example is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [address_components] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [long_name] => 1st Street
                                    [short_name] => 1st St
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => route
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [long_name] => Rock Hill
                                    [short_name] => Rock Hill
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => locality
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [long_name] => York
                                    [short_name] => York
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => administrative_area_level_2
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                            [3] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [long_name] => South Carolina
                                    [short_name] => SC
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => administrative_area_level_1
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                            [4] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [long_name] => United States
                                    [short_name] => US
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => country
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                            [5] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [long_name] => 29730
                                    [short_name] => 29730
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => postal_code
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [formatted_address] => 1st Street, Rock Hill, SC 29730, USA
                    [geometry] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [bounds] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [northeast] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [lat] => 34.9241861
                                            [lng] => -81.01329
                                        )

                                    [southwest] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [lat] => 34.923073
                                            [lng] => -81.0157245
                                        )

                                )

                            [location] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [lat] => 34.923658
                                    [lng] => -81.014494
                                )

                            [location_type] => GEOMETRIC_CENTER
                            [viewport] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [northeast] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [lat] => 34.924978530291
                                            [lng] => -81.013158269708
                                        )

                                    [southwest] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [lat] => 34.922280569709
                                            [lng] => -81.015856230292
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [partial_match] => 1
                    [types] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => route
                        )

                )

            [....more addresses here..]

        )

    [status] => OK
)
```

Comment: Hmm, still the same...empty output!